# Rep graph overlay bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Best expressed with a screenshot:

[image]

The little popup - with date and daily rep - is displayed all on one line, blocking each other.

Also, btw, horizontal scrollbar though not needed....

Comment: I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jin fixed the scrolling issue, and I tacked the tooltip one.  Under certain circumstances, IE9 takes `line-height` to mean **pixels** rather than as a raw number to multiple (like the spec, and every other browser does properly).  We gave it a `120%` line-height rather than a `1.2` to make it happy.